# count the `NULL` values in each column in sql table (c#)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ‘n’ columns in SQL table (let’s say 100 columns). I need to count the `NULL` values in each column.

For example:

```
 A  | B  | C
-------------
1   |NULL| 1
1   | 1  | NULL
NULL| 1  | 1
NULL|NULL| 1
```

Should output:

```
 A  |  B  |  C
---------------
 2  |  2  |  1
```

The example shows 3 columns. How would I get for let’s say 100 columns?

UPDATE:

I tried the following code:

```
public async Task<List<Column>> ValidateColumnAsync(string tableName)
{           
    var columns = new List<Column>();        
   
    var selectQuery = $@"

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ColumnNames
        
        CREATE TABLE ColumnNames (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        [name] varchar(max),
        nullCount int
        )

        INSERT INTO ColumnNames ([name]) 
        SELECT [name] FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('{tableName}')

        DECLARE @columnIndex INT = 1

        WHILE @columnIndex <= ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ColumnNames )
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @colName nvarchar(max) = (SELECT [name] FROM ColumnNames WHERE ID = @columnIndex)
            EXEC('SELECT ' + @colName + ' INTO colTable FROM {tableName}')

            DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'UPDATE ColumnNames SET nullCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) - COUNT(' + quotename(@colName) + ') FROM colTable) WHERE ID = @columnIndex'
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@columnIndex int', @columnIndex 

            DROP TABLE colTable
            SET @columnIndex = @columnIndex + 1
        END

        SELECT name, nullCount from ColumnNames
    ";
    
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {               
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                int name = reader.GetOrdinal("name");
                int nullCount = reader.GetOrdinal("nullCount");                     

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var response = new Column
                    {                               
                        Name = reader.GetString(name),
                        NullCount = reader.GetInt32(nullCount)
                    };
                    columns.Add(response);                           
                    
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }                

    return columns;
}
```

The sql query works however on running the above code, I see the error:

```
Azure CLI authentication timed out.
There is already an object named 'colTable' in the database
There is already an object named 'ColumnNames' in the database
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

You may need to apply `sum(isnull(col,1))` to each column

```
select sum(isnull(a,1)), sum(isnull(b,1)), sum(isnull(c,1)) .. from table;
```

Comment: I have around 100 columns. Is there a way to do this if the table has many columns and I don't want to explicitly write them all out?

Comment: @user989988
I dont think there is a simple way to list the "unknown" column. But you can try to query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to generate the SQL string first, then copy and run the generated SQL

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.